Calculation of maximum of a running average over a span of time
I have been working with a dataset of a toys production company. They have been producing toys since 1990. They have production in multiple locations all around the globe. I have a sheet which has the following data - serial no. of the toy, type of the toy, revision of the type of the toy, location where it was produced, feeder line used, machine used, date of start of production of the toy and completion of production of the toy. Each toy has it's own serial number. There are around 20 different types of toys. Most of the toys has had revisions at some point of time. A feeder line comprises of 2 machines which share the same feeder input (One could use only one machine per feeder line or both). So, if I have two feeder lines say, FL001 and FL002, then my machines could be FL001-M1, FL001-M2, FL002-M1 and FL002-M2. Now, I have around 200,000 rows of data and I'm about to analyse them in PowerBi.
I would like to know what is the maximum number of toys I've produced in each machines historically over a 365 day period. Because the production can vary week-on-week, there is a high chance that for machine FL001-M1, the max. no. of toys over a 365 day period is 400 over May 2011-April 2012 and FL001-M2 is 230 in June 1995-May 1996.
What I've tried to do is to first calculate
toys produced per day = calculate(countrows('Database')) 

Then I tried to calculate
Running average = calculate ([toys produced per day],
datesinperiod(
'Datebase'[Production Start Date],
lastdate('Datebase'[Production Start Date]),
-365,DAY))

Finally I calculated
365 day max. output per week = divide([Running average],52,0)


But I'm not sure if I'm calculating the maximum over the entire period of production in that particular machine or just the running average in the last 365 days of production in that machine.
Here is a model dataset.



Serial no.
Toy type
Toytype Revision
Location
Feederline
Machine
Production Start Date
End Date




TS0010105
TS
05
US
FL001
M1
19th August 1996
20th October 1996


TS0010206
TS
06
Eng
FL001
M2
10th June 2005
01st July 2005


PD0080209
PD
09
Jap
FL008
M2
13th April 2024
25th April 2024




Please edit your question to provide a sample dataset as text which can be copy/pasted (not a screenshot) so that we may easily reproduce your problem.

I've added a short table with 3 rows as a reference. Since it will be calculated over 52 weeks, I'm not sure of the best way to share a model dataset. Let me know if you have a better solution on how to share the model dataset (if needed) and I'll do it accordingly. :-)

Please provide sample data that someone can use to get to a sample answer that you are going to provide. "If you have this input, this should be the output, which I calculated like this, so help me get to that point"
